# In Express why does res.send() throw an error when an array item storing a number is sent, but not a string?

Tags: node.js, express

**Question:** In Express why does `res.send()` throw an error when an array item storing a number is sent, but not a complete array or a string?

**Example 1:** The following example works as expected.  The string value 10 is sent to the browser when the / route is requested.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    const obj = ['10', '100'];

    res.send(obj[0]);

});

// output 10
```

**Example 2:** The next example also works as expected.  The array holding 2 values, 10 and 100 is sent to the browser when the / route is requested.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    const obj = [10, 100];

    res.send(obj);

});

// output [10,100]
```

**Example 3:** This example does not work as expected.  Instead of the number 10 being sent to the browser an error is thrown that references the number 10.  I can't wrap my mind around this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    const obj = [10, 100];

    res.send(obj[0]);

});
```

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 10

Comment: It's upset by being given a number by the looks: [The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) if you want to send the number 10 as body content, it must be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending a number using `res.send()`, the number is identified as an HTTP status code. So `res.send(200)` will work but `res.send(10)` won't.

Answer (score 1):

you can not send only a number if you are developing an api you can send number wrapping in json object  you can send only string, HTML or json object

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    //send string
    res.send('hey')
    //or send HTML
    res.send('hii!!)
    //or json
    res.send({say: 'hey'})

});
```

docu [https://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#res.send]
Sends the HTTP response.
The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.